# Plot Interactive Decision Tree in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, jupyter, decision-tree

Is there a way to plot a decision tree in a Jupyter Notebook, such that I can interactively explore its nodes? I am thinking about something like this [image: dt]. This is an example from KNIME.

I have found https://planspace.org/20151129-see_sklearn_trees_with_d3/ and https://bl.ocks.org/ajschumacher/65eda1df2b0dd2cf616f and I know you can run d3 in Jupyter, but I have not found any packages, that do that.

Comment: Try using Jupyter Javascript Magic to insert a javascript snippet: http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Notebook/JavaScript%20Notebook%20Extensions.html

Comment: Maybe this package could help you if you can pass the subset data of the node that you clicked on : [Treeviz](https://github.com/PierreCapo/treeviz) Disclaim : I made this package.

Comment: The example in question combined with @NicolòGasparini comment should do the trick. Is the question more about if there is a way or is an acceptable answer limited to naming a package does the visualization?

Answer (score 13):

**Updated Answer with collapsible graph using d3js in Jupyter Notebook**

**Start of 1st cell in notebook**

```
%%html
<div id="d3-example"></div>
<style>

.node circle {
  cursor: pointer;
  stroke: #3182bd;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  pointer-events: none;
  text-anchor: middle;
}

line.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #9ecae1;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
</style>
```

**End of 1st cell in notebook**

**Start of 2nd cell in notebook**

```
%%javascript
// We load the d3.js library from the Web.
require.config({paths:
    {d3: "http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min"}});
require(["d3"], function(d3) {
  // The code in this block is executed when the
  // d3.js library has been loaded.

  // First, we specify the size of the canvas
  // containing the visualization (size of the
  // <div> element).
  var width = 960,
    height = 500,
    root;

  // We create a color scale.
  var color = d3.scale.category10();

  // We create a force-directed dynamic graph layout.
//   var force = d3.layout.force()
//     .charge(-120)
//     .linkDistance(30)
//     .size([width, height]);
    var force = d3.layout.force()
    .linkDistance(80)
    .charge(-120)
    .gravity(.05)
    .size([width, height])
    .on("tick", tick);
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var link = svg.selectAll(".link"),
    node = svg.selectAll(".node");

  // In the <div> element, we create a <svg> graphic
  // that will contain our interactive visualization.
 var svg = d3.select("#d3-example").select("svg")
  if (svg.empty()) {
    svg = d3.select("#d3-example").append("svg")
          .attr("width", width)
          .attr("height", height);
  }
var link = svg.selectAll(".link"),
    node = svg.selectAll(".node");
  // We load the JSON file.
  d3.json("graph2.json", function(error, json) {
    // In this block, the file has been loaded
    // and the 'graph' object contains our graph.
 if (error) throw error;
else
    test(1);
root = json;
      test(2);
      console.log(root);
  update();



  });
    function test(rr){console.log('yolo'+String(rr));}

function update() {
    test(3);
  var nodes = flatten(root),
      links = d3.layout.tree().links(nodes);

  // Restart the force layout.
  force
      .nodes(nodes)
      .links(links)
      .start();

  // Update links.
  link = link.data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

  link.exit().remove();

  link.enter().insert("line", ".node")
      .attr("class", "link");

  // Update nodes.
  node = node.data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id; });

  node.exit().remove();

  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .on("click", click)
      .call(force.drag);

  nodeEnter.append("circle")
      .attr("r", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.size) / 10 || 4.5; });

  nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

  node.select("circle")
      .style("fill", color);
}
    function tick() {
  link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

  node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
}
          function color(d) {
  return d._children ? "#3182bd" // collapsed package
      : d.children ? "#c6dbef" // expanded package
      : "#fd8d3c"; // leaf node
}
      // Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
  if (d3.event.defaultPrevented) return; // ignore drag
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  update();
}
    function flatten(root) {
  var nodes = [], i = 0;

  function recurse(node) {
    if (node.children) node.children.forEach(recurse);
    if (!node.id) node.id = ++i;
    nodes.push(node);
  }

  recurse(root);
  return nodes;
}

});
```

**End of 2nd cell in notebook**

**Contents of graph2.json**

```
   {
 "name": "flare",
 "children": [
  {
   "name": "analytics"
    },
    {
   "name": "graph"
    }
   ]
}
```

**The graph**
[image]

Click on flare, which is the root node, the other nodes will collapse

[image]

**Github repository for notebook used here**: [Collapsible tree in ipython notebook](https://github.com/mohdkashif93/Collapsible-tree-in-Ipython-notebook)

**References**

- [Collapsible graph in d3.js](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1093130)
- [Networkx graph in notebook using d3.js](https://ipython-books.github.io/64-visualizing-a-networkx-graph-in-the-notebook-with-d3js/)

**Old Answer**

I found [this tutorial here](https://towardsdatascience.com/interactive-visualization-of-decision-trees-with-jupyter-widgets-ca15dd312084) for interactive visualization of Decision Tree in Jupyter Notebook.

**Install graphviz**

There are 2 steps for this :
Step 1: Install graphviz for python using pip

```
pip install graphviz
```

Step 2: Then you have to install graphviz seperately. Check this [link](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/download/).
Then based on your system OS you need to set the path accordingly:

For windows and Mac OS [check this link](https://enterprise-architecture.org/downloads?id=208). 
For Linux/Ubuntu [check this link](https://serverfault.com/questions/575239/error-unable-to-find-dot-command-of-the-graphviz-package)

**Install ipywidgets**

Using pip

```
pip install ipywidgets
jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension
```

Using conda

```
conda install -c conda-forge ipywidgets
```

Now for the code

```
from IPython.display import SVG
from graphviz import Source
from sklearn.datasets load_iris
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier, export_graphviz
from sklearn import tree
from ipywidgets import interactive
from IPython.display import display
```

**Load the dataset, say for instance iris dataset in this case**

```
data = load_iris()

#Get the feature matrix
features = data.data

#Get the labels for the sampels
target_label = data.target

#Get feature names
feature_names = data.feature_names
```

**Function to plot the decision tree **

```
def plot_tree(crit, split, depth, min_split, min_leaf=0.17):
    classifier = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state = 123, criterion = crit, splitter = split, max_depth = depth, min_samples_split=min_split, min_samples_leaf=min_leaf)
    classifier.fit(features, target_label)

    graph = Source(tree.export_graphviz(classifier, out_file=None, feature_names=feature_names, class_names=['0', '1', '2'], filled = True))

    display(SVG(graph.pipe(format='svg')))
return classifier
```

**Call the function**

```
decision_plot = interactive(plot_tree, crit = ["gini", "entropy"], split = ["best", "random"]  , depth=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], min_split=(0.1,1), min_leaf=(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.5))

display(decision_plot)
```

You will get the following the graph
[image]

**You can change the parameters interactively in the output cell by the chnaging the following values**

[image]

**Another decision tree on the same data but different parameters**
[image]

References :

- [Using ipywidgets to plot interactive decision trees](https://medium.com/@daphne.sive/interactive-visualization-of-decision-trees-with-jupyter-widgets-ca15dd312084)
- [Plotting decision trees in python](https://medium.com/@rnbrown/creating-and-visualizing-decision-trees-with-python-f8e8fa394176)
- [ipywidgets](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
- [In case you get issues with Graphviz](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/1666)
- [scikit-learn issue :Improve decision tree plotting in Jupyter environment](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/6261)

Comment: Unfortunatelly, this is not the answer I was looking for. You describe, how to build different decision trees, using different input parameters. I am interested in exploring a single decision tree. That is, interactively collapsing and expanding decision tree nodes in order to understand the prediction its making. Also my decision tree might be very large (10-100s) of nodes.

Comment: @r0f1 I have updated my answer based on your comments. Now it uses d3.js to expand/collapse tree. This is a small example using only 3 nodes. If this answer helped you, please mark it as the correct one (and/or upvote) :)

Comment: Hey @r0f1, you jus need to create the json file and nodes will be created accordingly. This is an example of force directed gaph, you can use any other graph here as well(including the heiraricahl graph you suggested in the question)

Answer (score 6):

**1.** In case you simply want to use D3 in Jupyter, here is a tutorial: https://medium.com/@stallonejacob/d3-in-juypter-notebook-685d6dca75c8

[image]

[image]

**2.** For building an interactive decision tree, here is another interesting GUI toolkit called the TMVAGui.

In this the code is just one-liner:
`factory.DrawDecisionTree(dataset, "BDT")`

https://indico.cern.ch/event/572131/contributions/2315243/attachments/1343269/2023816/gsoc16_4thpresentation.pdf

Answer (score 1):

There is a module called pydot. You can create graphs and add edges to make a decision tree.

```
import pydot # 

graph = pydot.Dot(graph_type='graph')
edge1 = pydot.Edge('1', '2', label = 'edge1')
edge2 = pydot.Edge('1', '3', label = 'edge2')
graph.add_edge(edge1)
graph.add_edge(edge2)

graph.write_png('my_graph.png')
```

This is an example that would output a png file of your decision tree. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I found a GitHub project that is based on interactive Decision Tree building. 
Maybe this could be of help:

This is based on r2d3 library which takes in Json script and creates an interactive mapping of a Decision Tree.

https://github.com/yamad/r2d3-decision-tree